# How can I access a component(for example a timepicker) in one activity from another activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, timepicker, android-timepicker

I want to access a timepicker in an activity from another activity in the same app. For example, if I change the time in the timepicker in one activity, the time in the timepicker in the other activity should also change accordingly. How can I do this?

Comment: you wanna access it or any way might be ok for you?

Comment: Any way is okay. But it should do what I want to do. That is the only condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use putExtra to pass data to your new intent.

```
int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
String time = hour + ":" + minute;

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(time, "timeData");
startActivity(intent)
```

To view the time.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   String value = extras.getString("timeData");
   //do stuff with the time now...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can pass the hour and minute separately. Right?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes you can. just add putExtra

Answer (score 0):

I guess if i am right , you may like to pass your date attributes to next activity 
using an Intent , and then set the state of the timepicker with those values in next activity . Here is a sample , what you may/should do `i.putExtra("day", day);
            i.putExtra("month", month);
            i.putExtra("year", year);` . If you are not familiar with intents , have a look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!